# How to update records programmatically in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access, ado, recordset

I am trying to ad an event counter to a table.

The table contains some data about events organized by the subject of an event (`NR_U`) and subsequet period (`C_ID`).

The counter should count the number of periods since the last event defined as (`D_Z>90 and K_Z>200`) for all subjects and periods in the table.

I wrote the following, but at the `rs.update`.

I get run time error `3251`:

> The current recordset does not allow update.

How do I fix it, so the records can be updated?

```
Private Sub update_default()
    Dim Conn1 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim Cmd1 As New ADODB.Command
    Dim Errs1 As Errors
    Dim Rs As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim s As String
    Dim un As String
    Dim m As Double

    Set Conn1 = CurrentProject.Connection
    s = "SELECT * FROM MAIN order by MAIN.NR_U, MAIN_4.C_ID;"
    un = "nothing"

    Set Rs = Conn1.Execute(s)

    While Not Rs.EOF
        If Rs!NR_U = un Then
            If (Rs!D_Z > 90 And Rs!K_Z > 200) Then
                m = 1
            Else
                m = IIf(m > 0, m + 1, 0)
                m = IIf(m >= 12, 0, m)
            End If
        Else
            un = Rs!NR_U
            m = 0
            If (Rs!D_Z > 90 And Rs!K_Z > 200) Then
                m = 1
            End If
        End If

        Rs!D_C_12M = m
        Rs.update
        Rs.MoveNext
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: You shouldn't store calculated (dynamic) values in the table. Use a query.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand. I cannot use a query for this purpose. I need to loop through the table, calculate the number of periods from last event for each record, update the record and move on.

Comment: Can't see why a query cannot be used.

Comment: Because queries update all records fullfilling certain criteria - those criteria are fixed for the query in the SQL statement (fixed means identical for all the records affected by the query). In my case the criteria for update change (number of records between an event end current record, subject of the event) change with each individual record.

Comment: You misunderstand. No update query. Leave the table as is and create a Select query to calculate the desired output whenever you need it.

Comment: But the whole point is that I need to update each record in a table sequentially - based on the information contained in the previous records. All I need, is a simple program that will move from record to record in a table untill it reaches the end of file and at each step it will allow to modify one value in the current record.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've managed to solve the problem. Instead of

"Rs.Execute(s)" I've used "Rs.Open s, Conn1, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockOptimistic" and evrything worked just fine.